# joi validation for passing key value pair to other schema

Tags: node.js, joi

I have a object like

```
{
"a": {
    "name": "name of a",
    "year": "1"
},
"b": {
    "name": "name of b",
    "year": "2"
},
"c": {
    "name": "name of c",
    "year": "123456"
}
}
```

I'm using the below validation

```
var mainobject=Joi.object().pattern(/^/,subObject),
var suboject=joi.object({
name:joi.string(),
year:joi.string()
})
```

With this code, can I be able to iterate through objects?Is there anything wrong with my first code? Here in the main object, I used pattern for unknown keys. If I want to include one more data like details,

```
{
"a": {
"name": "name of a",
"year": "1"
"details":(should include name and year in "name":'name of a',"year":'1')
},
"b": {
"name": "name of b",
"year": "2"
},
"c": {
"name": "name of c",
"year": "123456"
}
}
```

How can I achieve the above solution? Please, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.unknown()` API](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.0/API.md#objectunknownallow) to allow unknown key.

```
var subobject = Joi.object({
  name:Joi.string(),
  year:Joi.string()
}).unknown();
```